# Relay All mails of a domain with a SMTP server and store it

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

A customer have a domain on google apps and he wants to archive all the mail that come to the MTA server.

I think that I can add a SMTP server to receive the email which would send all the emails to google apps, with postfix for example which would relay them and store it.

is it the right solution ? How is possible to consult the email after ?

Answer (score 0):

It maybe more practical to setup the Google account to auto-forward all the emails it gets to a 'Archive' email address.

Google Apps Email interface -> setting -> Forwarding -> 'Add a forwarding address'

Comment: well you are right, my client fear that some employes share some secret and he would like a shadow server

Comment: @P.Sohm  It is fairly easy for employees to route through a secondary server if they want to leak information.  For this case you really want restrict the outgoing MTA.  Without remailing, you may have delivery issues forwarding into Gmail from a primary MX.